# How to display kivy panels vertically in a .kv file?

Tags: python, kivy

I have my kivy file and my python file. I can display my panels and show their content when they are click but the panels are oriented horizontally. I want these tabs to be displayed vertically. I have tried using

```
orientation: "vertical"
```

This is not a duplicate question I have checked around and never really found an answer. Here is the code:

```
    <SampBoxLayout>:
orientation: "vertical"
padding: 10
spacing: 10


BoxLayout:
    orientation: "vertical"
    height: 30

    BoxLayout:
        orientation: "vertical"
        size_hint_x: .25
        size_hint_y: .25

        TabbedPanel:
            do_default_tab: False
            size: 5, 5

            TabbedPanelItem:
                text: "Home"
                Label:
                    text: "Content of Home"
            TabbedPanelItem:
                text: "Browse"
                Label:
                    text: "Content of Browse"
            TabbedPanelItem:
                text: "Radio"
                Label:
                    text: "Content of Radio"
            TabbedPanelItem:
                text: "Made for You"
                Label:
                    text: "Content of Made For You"
            TabbedPanelItem:
                text: "Recently Played"
                Label:
                    text: "Content of Recently Played"
            TabbedPanelItem:
                text: "Favorite Songs"
                Label:
                    text: "Content of Recent Songs"
            TabbedPanelItem:
                text: "Albums"
                Label:
                    text: "Content of Albums"
            TabbedPanelItem:
                text: "Artists"
                Label:
                    text: "Content of Artists"
            TabbedPanelItem:
                text: "Stations"
                Label:
                    text: "Content of Stations"
            TabbedPanelItem:
                text: "Local Files"
                Label:
                    text: "Content of Local Files"
            TabbedPanelItem:
                text: "Videos"
                Label:
                    text: "Content of Videos"
            TabbedPanelItem:
                text: "Videos"
                Label:
                    text: "Content of Videos"
            TabbedPanelItem:
                text: "Podcasts"
                Label:
                    text: "Content of Podc
```

Comment: Just to clarify, I need the panels items to be listed vertically. Those who know kivy should know what I mean. instead of several
        TabbedPanels I want the TabbedPanelItems to be going vertically

Comment: In this case if the code is necessary and obligatory since you indicate: *... The panels are oriented horizontally. I want these tabs to be displayed vertically. I have tried using:` orientation: "vertical"`* that is, you have tried something that seems right and it did not work, so without code your question falls on the off-topic: *"why isn't this code working?"*. So in conclusion if you want help provide a [mcve]

Comment: Your code may not be necessary for you to ask the question, but it is necessary for us to produce a sensible answer. Please post a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @eyllanesc, thanks for the info!!

Comment: No you dont even need the code to answer the question but here I will edit the question and show the code

Comment: The code works just fine I need something to make those panels vertical

Comment: And I would like to know how I can improve these questions because someone voted it down.

Comment: @HrittikChatterjee How much does it cost to provide a [mcve]? If you need your question to be good you will have to work a little more. If you think that the solution does not require code then show the solution :-) since for you it seems that the solution is simple. Its code is not an MCVE because it is not complete nor is it reproducible. :-)

Comment: I see. ok thanks for the feedback. I still dont have an answer though does anyone know?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you want, you need to add the `tab_pos` property to your `TabbedPanel`, like:

```
    TabbedPanel:
        do_default_tab: False
        tab_pos: 'left_top'
```

And unless you are doing something else with them, you don't need all those `BoxLayout` items.

Comment: This works to do what I asked with one problem. It does not change the text orientation so the text is sideways. How can I fix this?

Comment: That is a feature of the `TabbedPanel`. It can probably be customized to look the way you want, but it would be a lot of work. It would likely be easier to just layout a column of `ToggleButtons` on the left and a single content on the right (maybe an `AnchorLayout`). Then program the toggle buttons to switch the content.